# load multiple .rdata files at once

Tags: r, load, rdata

I'd like to load multiple .Rdata files into R with a single code line. I came across a bunch of threads on this forum that provides solutions on how to do this. But all the solutions assume that the working directory is the same as where the files are saved. In my case, the files I'd like to load are in a subfolder of the working directory, hence I get an error returned when trying to run the code stating that there's no such file or directory. Below is the code that i tried with error message:

```
file_list <- list.files("data files", pattern = "rp.")

lapply(file_list,load,.GlobalEnv)

Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'rp.depth.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Any advice on how to adapt the below code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the online doc for the `full.names` argument to `list.files`.

Comment: It's useful to look at `file_list` which likely looks like `c("rp1.rda", "rp2.rda")`, and if you do `file.exists(file_list[1])` it will return `FALSE`, because the files are in a subdirectory. R is not going to infer that when you said `"data files"` earlier, that it should apply that different-path to any or all subsequent operations. `load` is going to be rather literal and try to load exactly what you tell it to, and that isn't working.

Comment: @Limey, do you know of a good dupe-link for this? I've seen it often enough that it'd be good to have a canonical answer for it.

Comment: @r2evans I'm sorry if i wasn't clear, but i wasn't looking to receive a diagnosis of my the issue, i know what the issue is. I was looking for a solution to the issue.

Comment: @Limey Ok got it, that works. I was thinking of a solution dealing with specifying load(), but this is way easier.

Comment: Sorry, @FlyingDutch, I was explaining what would have helped you reduce the problem. Often part of helping questions here is explaining what steps can be taken to determine the root of the problem. If you knew that the paths were wrong, why did you attempt `load`? If in some notional troubleshooting session, `load("rp1.rda")` failed, then `load("data files/rp1.rda")` worked, then ... how do we make `file_list` reflect the real paths? Too many early-programmers have little debugging experience, I find helping with that can be useful, I apologize if that was not what you wanted.

Comment: @r2evens.  No I don't.   I did look, but couldn't find one.  I think your explanation to OP is highly relevant.  Almost all of the questions I found are along the lines of "Why can't I open my file with `readRDS`/`load`/etc  when I know it exists?".  There is a failure to diagnose the root cause and recognise that the problem lies elsewhere in the code.  The debugging skills of early programmers are often weak.  The best way to gain skill is by making mistakes.  I have made many!